# Could not find module 'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal308.dll' (or one of its dependencies)

Tags: python, django, postgis, gdal, geodjango

I'm trying to use GeoDjango + gdal + PostGis in order to create a map application.

OSGeo4W is completelly installed, and all the dll files are there

When I run this command:

```
python3 manage.py check
```

I get the following result:

```
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal308.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

However the files are correctly existing in the location. Here is how my settings file looks like, for the gdal part:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\\OSGeo4W"
    # if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
    #     OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\\share\\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\\share\\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = OSGEO4W + r"\\bin\\gdal308.dll"
```

Could someone who has gone through this please help me shed some light over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are to "new". GeoDjango only supports GDAL up to v.3.7.

Read the documentation: [**Django DOCs - Installing Geospatial libraries**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#installing-geospatial-libraries)

[image]

Comment: I have changed the parameter to   GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = OSGEO4W + r"\\bin\\gdal307.dll", even though I'm getting the same error: Could not find module 'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal307.dll'

Comment: Ok I got what you said... I could download the gdal-3.7.3 folder from the GDal website... but the folders look different from the one I've downloaded as OSGeo4W... how do I need to fill up settings.py parameters for this folder?

Comment: No, no..., why so complicated? Just use your OSGeo4W installation wizard and change to a compatible version (I updated the answer to add an image). There are dependencies within theses libraries. You can't just change GDAL to another version. I mean, you can try... and hope for the best..., but as you experienced this most probably won't work